# Show that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}[\log_{2}(n/i)]$ is O(n), hint use Stirling's Approximation

Tags: summation, induction, asymptotics

Assume that n is a power of 2. Hint 1: Use induction to reduce the problem to that for n/2. Hint 2: Alternative hint -> use Stirling's Approximation. Im trying to solve this problem using the lime rule for big oh which says the lim n->inf (f(n)/g(n)) = 0≤c< inf. My instictive approach would be to use arithmetic sequence formula to simplify the summation into something i can take the limit of but im not sure what I would do with i. Does the i become a factorial?

Comment: Alternate proof: The right-endpoint Riemann sum of a decreasing nonnegative function is a lower bound for the integral, so $$0 \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} \log_2\!\left(\frac{1}{i/n}\right)\frac{1}{n} \leq \int_0^1 \log_2\!\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)dx = \frac{1}{\ln 2}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Recall that $\log(a) + \log(b) = \log(ab)$.  Applying this to your case gives $$ \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n \log_2(n/i) = \log_2\left(\prod_{i = 1}^n \frac{n}{i} \right) = \log_2 \left( \frac{n^n}{n!}\right). $$

Can you complete the problem with Stirling's formula?

---

Edit: We have \begin{align*}
\log_2 \left( \frac{n^n}{n!}\right) &= \frac{1}{\ln 2}\left(n \ln(n) - \ln(n!) \right) \\
&=  \frac{1}{\ln 2}\bigg(n \ln(n) - \Big[n \ln(n) - n + O(\ln(n)) \Big] \bigg) &\text{ by Stirling's formula} \\
&=\frac{1}{\ln 2}\bigg(n - O(\ln(n)) \bigg) \\
&= O(n).
\end{align*}

Comment: Cool, makes sense. For sterling's formula it says where ε(n) is O(1/n^2). How does this simplify in my formula since I want to take the limit of it?

Comment: Ok I now realize that the $n^n$ in the numerator and denominator cancel which leaves me with $\log((\sqrt{2\pi n} \left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^n
\left(1+\frac{1}{12n}+\epsilon(n)\right))^{-1})$ Im still not sure what to do with $\epsilon(n)$ or how to take the limit from here. Do I need lhospital since Id be taking log of 0 as n approaches inf?

Comment: @yako, It seems like you've spent some time on this, so I'll write it out a bit more.

Comment: Im having trouble figuring out how you went from ln(n!) to $\Big[n \ln(n) - n + O(\ln(n)) \Big]$. I tried taking ln on both sides of stirlings equation $n! \approx \sqrt{2\pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n
\left(1+\frac{1}{12n}+\epsilon(n)\right)$ but got $ln(\sqrt{2\pi n})+\ln(n)-n+\ln(1+\frac{1}{12n}+O(\frac{1}{n^2}))$

Comment: [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) states that $\ln(n!) =n\ln(n) - n + O(\ln(n))$